# Trouble with SOAP request from Flex

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, soap, namespaces

**SUM:** I ended up having to form the XML manually. I also had to create an Operation and use its send(); method rather than just doing something like WebService.MyServiceFunction(); - not sure why that was the case.

I send off the request as follows:

```
            var xm:XML =
                <SetPropertiesForCurrentUser xmlns="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200">
                    <values xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <d4p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                            <d4p1:Key>{obj.Key}</d4p1:Key>
                            <d4p1:Value xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d6p1:string">{obj.Value}</d4p1:Value>
                        </d4p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
                    </values>
                </SetPropertiesForCurrentUser>;

            var profileService:WebService = new WebService();
            profileService.useProxy = false;
            profileService.loadWSDL(url);

            var o:Operation = profileService.SetPropertiesForCurrentUser;
            o.send(xm);
```

---

Here’s my scenario:

I have ASP.NET web services to handle authentication, user roles, and user profiles (default ASP.NET AuthenticationService, RoleService, and ProfileService, to be exact).

So from my Flex web app, I am able to successfully call the ASP.NET service. For example, something like this works fine:

```
var profileService:WebService = new WebService();
profileService.useProxy = false;
profileService.GetAllPropertiesForCurrentUser.addEventListener("result",getAllPropertiesForCurrentUser_EventHandler);
profileService.addEventListener("fault",getAllPropertiesForCurrentUserFault_EventHandler);
profileService.loadWSDL(url);
profileService.GetAllPropertiesForCurrentUser();
```

I run into trouble when I need to pass a Dictionary object to another function on the service (SetPropertiesForCurrentUser). The .NET service asks for this type of value:

System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object)

Here are the two pertinent entries from the web.config entry from my ASP.NET service:

```
    <properties>
        <clear/>
        <add name="coordinateFormat" />
    </properties>
...
    <profileService enabled="true"
      readAccessProperties="coordinateFormat"
      writeAccessProperties="coordinateFormat"/>
```

So after putting together a SOAP request from a Silverlight app (which works as expected) I’ve narrowed it down to a difference in the XML request sent to the SOAP handler:

From Flex:

```
<tns:Value>DMS</tns:Value>
```

From Silverlight:

```
<d4p1:Value xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d6p1:string">DMS</d4p1:Value>
```

If I take the request generated by Flex, catch it with Fiddler, modify that one line to include the “type” namespace – it works.

Anyone have an idea how I can get that namespace onto my variable that is passed to the SOAP handler from Actionscript? Here is my code for sending off that SetPropertiesForCurrentUser function:

```
var obj:Object = {};
obj["Key"] = "coordinateFormat";
obj["Value"] = DMS;

var profileService:WebService = new WebService();
profileService.useProxy = false;
profileService.SetPropertiesForCurrentUser.addEventListener("result",setPropertiesForCurrentUser_EventHandler);
profileService.addEventListener("fault",setPropertiesForCurrentUserFault_EventHandler);
profileService.loadWSDL(url);
profileService.SetPropertiesForCurrentUser(new ArrayCollection([obj]),false);
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_06.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default SOAPEncoder that is used is some what limited in its capabilities (like not including the type attribute you mentioned above).  Luckily, there is a way to control that by writing your own encoder.

see this link at adobe (read part about using custom web service serialization) [Link on Adobe's Site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf66651-7fe5)

Comment: Thanks for leading me down the right path. Turns out I did not have to extend SOAPEncoder, I just formed the XML manually and sent the request using mx.rpc.soap.Operation.send(), which, for some reason, performs differently from WebService.myWebServiceFunction()

Comment: yeah that works also as is mentioned in the doc there.  I just usually prefer the path of writing a class to handle it so I don't accidentally make mistakes.  Glad your working!!!